# tag/keyword link change out going location

Tags: php, wordpress

Would it be easy to change the tag and keywords out bound link as the same as view website button?

if it is would you mind sharing the info with me?

[image]

I got the link code from the button but need to find the loaction of the tags:

```
<?php $PPTDesign->CustomFields($post,""); ?>
```